# Run python file inside another

Tags: python

I am using python 3.5

I want to run a python script calling from another python script.

In particular, say I have script A (in particular, this is the exact file that I want to run: [script A file](https://github.com/allanzelener/YAD2K/blob/master/retrain_yolo.py)):

Script A is the following.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    _main(args)
```

---

**I am running script B, inside script B, it calls script A. 
How do I simply do this by calling the main function of script A while running script B?**

---

Please no `os.system('python scriptA.py 1')`, this is not what i want. thanks

Answer (score 2):

normally you can import it and call the main function
like

```
import script_a
...
script_a._main()
```

of course it could be that the script_a is not in you src structure, so that you can not simple import, or script_a is completely somewhere else.
Suppose the path of the script_a is path_a
you can

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path_a)
import script_a
script_a._main()
```

if you want to pass the args to script_a , in your script_b

```
import script_a
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    script_a._main(args)
```

Comment: but it has `args = argparser.parse_args()`

Comment: @wrek as you would prepare those arguments somehow, there is no problem with passing them to _main directly.

Comment: I thought I have to do `args = script_a.argparser.parse_args()`. Then `script_a._main(args)`

Comment: I can simply do `script_a._main()` in one shot?

Answer (score 1):

In Script B simply import Script A,

```
import script_A
```

or

```
from script_A import *
```

now you can access your script A in script B

Comment: how do I call that `main` thing

Comment: if you import * you can access all function which is present in script a

Answer (score 1):

Treat the file like a module and put `import scriptA` at the top of your file.

You can then use `scriptA.main(1)` where `1` is the argument you are passing to it.

**N.B** When importing do not put `.py` at the end.

Comment: why do i have a `1`, I dont need to pass anything

Comment: You literally have `os.system('python scriptA.py 1')` in your question .... your example is passing 1 LMAO also all the other answers changed the name of your script..

Comment: I thought I have to do `args = script_a.argparser.parse_args()`. Then `script_a._main(args)`

Comment: I can simply do `script_a.main()` in one shot?

Comment: @wrek try it and see what happens? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have code which is not indented inside of script A and if you import script A inside script B, it will automatically first run script A and then move on to the `__main__()` of script B. How ever if you wish control when the execution of script A begins, then , indent your code in Script A or code it in a normal function such as `def start()` .

Now, import Script A into Script B as follows

```
import ScriptA
```

And run the script A as

```
ScriptA.start()
```

NOTE: Make sure that script A and script B are in the same directory for this to work. Hope this solves your purpose. Cheers!

Comment: The things you describe (automatically started __main__() and postponed execution of imported scripts) do not exist.

Comment: You are right. I got confused . Now it should be alright